# How to get category image custom post type taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, terms, categories, images

I have a custom post `estate_property` and its has taxonomies `property_category` ,`propert_action`.I have installed `WPCustom Category Image`  to upload image for each category of taxonomies. How to display the uploaded image .I search for it but failed to display image 
My code is

```
$taxonomy_name = 'property_category';
$asd=get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy_name); 
var_dump($asd);
```

it returns nothing .Help please

Answer (score 1):

From the details page of the WPCustom Category Image Plug-in  : https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wpcustom-category-image

**1st** - Go to Wp-Admin -> Posts(or post type) -> Categories (or taxonomy) to see Custom Category Image options.

**2nd** ...depending on whether you want to show a single category image or display several in a loop -

//SINGLE

```
echo do_shortcode('[wp_custom_image_category onlysrc="https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/false" size="full" term_id="123" alt="alt :)"]');
```

//LOOP

```
foreach( get_categories(['hide_empty' => false]) as $category) {
    echo $category->name . '<br>';
    echo do_shortcode(sprintf('[wp_custom_image_category term_id="%s"]',$category->term_id));
}
```

In addition there is an example category template here -

https://gist.github.com/eduardostuart/b88d6845a1afb78c296c

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the WPCustom Category Image plugin, but it probably need another function something like `get_category_image($category_id)` (or something like that) to retrieve the image.

Answer (score 0):

If get_the_terms returns nothing, you'll need to check for $wp_error return. This function will return an array of terms objects on success, false if there are no terms or the post does not exist, WP_Error on failure (i.e:taxonomy doesn't exist).

just modify your code like this :

```
$taxonomy_name = 'property_category';
$asd=get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy_name); 

if(is_wp_error($asd){
    $error_string = $asd->get_error_message();
    var_dump($error_string); 
}
else{
    var_dump($asd); 
}
```

There is many chances that the category image is stored as a term_meta, that you can grab with the get_term_meta() function. This function works like get_post_meta.

The same as above where you'll need to modify the key to get the right meta, or just put the first parameter to get an array of all the metas for the term_id.

```
$taxonomy_name = 'property_category';
$asd=get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy_name); 

if(is_wp_error($asd){
    $error_string = $asd->get_error_message();
    var_dump($error_string); 
}
else{
    var_dump($asd); 
    foreach($asd as $term){
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_image = get_term_meta($term_id, 'image_category', true); //false returns an array
        var_dump($term_image);
    }
}
```